# File watcher doesn't generate CSS from Less file in PhpStorm

Tags: css, wordpress, less, phpstorm, file-watcher

I'm trying to setup a file watcher for my `style.less` file.

- path to my less file: `themes/lessbuilt/less/style.less`
- path to my css file: `themes/lessbuilt/css`

In my `style.less` file I've just referenced a child theme and added some variables:

```
//style.less
@import "../../maxstore/style.css";
@font-family:'Rabbid-Highway-sign-ii', sans-serif;
@highlight: #d77832;

body{
    background-color:green;
}
h1.site-title {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: @font-family;
}
.header-categories .accordion-toggle{
    background-color:@highlight;
}
```

I'm using a mac and here's the screenshot of my configuration

[image]

I still unable to generate my `style.css` file from my `style.less` file.

Comment: 1) So .. what command gets actually executed (should be show in console)? 2) It that command (paths etc) correct? 3) Does that command works if executed in the same folder but in native terminal (not launched from IDE)? Right now it might be about wrong paths (not enough arguments)...

Comment: Here on Windows (using globally installed compiler) I'm using this (old setup (3 or so years old).. but still works fine) for "Arguments"  field: `$FileName$ ../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.css` -- as you can see I have both files -- .less and .css  -- https://postimg.org/image/yqmjytgmt/

Answer (score 1):

You should have both less file path and css file path in Arguments

`$FileName$ ../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`